# Implementing pull to refresh view feature

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, pull-to-refresh

Can we implement pull to refresh feature on a custom view controller?. My view controller is not a table view controller and I want to refresh this view on pulling the screen down. How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In short, you need to do the following:

1. Embed your view in a `UIScrollView`.
2. Set your controller as the delegate of the scroll view.
3. Add a "Pull To Refresh" subview to the scroll view such that its frame is off the top of the screen. Something like `CGRectMake(0, -30, 320, 30)` for a 30pt-tall indicator view.
4. Implement `–scrollViewDidScroll:` to update your "Pull to Refresh" view as the user is dragging.
5. Implement `–scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` to check `scrollView.contentOffset` when the dragging ends. If it's beyond your threshold for refreshing, then do the refresh.