# pull to refresh scrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, stack, pull-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing pull to refresh view feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392048/implementing-pull-to-refresh-view-feature)

Are there any sample outs out there that show you how to implement the pull Related threads on iPhone Dev SDK Forum" Chpwn's pull to refresh  Google+ Project Aims to Pull Down Facebook from Social Networking.

Comment: First link from googling "pull to refresh" http://blog.leahculver.com/2010/12/iphone-pull-to-refresh.html

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh - I like this one, its plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have this one https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ["Pull to reload" option](http://three20.pypt.lt/pull-to-reload-implementation-in-tttableviewcontroller) in [Three20](http://three20.info/)'s TTTableViewController