# Pull to refresh - Solution found but unable to implement it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the example shown in the [Pulltorefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) library. They have implemented it to fit a TableViewController class. But mine is a UIViewController, and i am adding a TableView in it.

I found a SO answer that shows a workaround for this. Can someone tell me how to implement it as described in the SO answer. [Here's the link for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392145/844872)

Answer (score 0):

That answer is not talking about using the library you are referencing. They are talking about how you would go about creating a UIScrollView with the "pull to refresh" functionality.

It shouldn't be that hard to transition the code to a UIViewController. Just change the code to subclass UIViewController and setup a UITableView property on the view controller (and make sure to set the data source & delegate of the UITableView to the view controller). There might be more to it but these are the basics. If you ask a more specific question about how to transition it to a UIViewController then maybe I (or someone else) can help more.

Comment: Well, i am unable to add the data source & delegate of the PullToRefresh class to my viewController.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try a different library?

I've used this one in the past, and it worked great!

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotableviewpullrefresh

Edit:

Here is the exact tutorial I used. He does exactly what you want. Adds the pull to refresh to a UITableView that is contained in a UIViewController!

Comment: I need to add this feature to my UITableView which is in a UIViewController. I couldn't find a single example that does so. HELP