# UITableView scroll to a specific point when scrollViewDidEndDragging

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a `UITableView` which is scrollable. When the user scrolls the `UITableView` a certain amount and then releases their finger, instead of scrolling back to the top, I want it to scroll 50 points from the top, effectively leaving a gap of 50 points between the top of the screen and the top most cell.

At the moment I have implemented `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, but I don't know how to set where the view will scroll back to.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work as desired.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    // If scrolled over 100 points
    if(-100 > (double)self.tableView.contentOffset.y) {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -50) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The code above causes a weird flicker, like the animations are both running concurrently, but I'm unsure.

Any help would be appreciated.

### UPDATE with more information

I'm implementing "Pull down to refresh" functionality based upon this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392145/120615

I've added an extra `UIView` to the top of the `UITableView` and when you scroll the `UITableView`, the `UIView` moves down into view. When you release your finger from the screen, the `UITableView` scrolls back to the top hiding the new `UIView` I've added.

What I would **like** to happen is that when you release your finger the `UITableView` scrolls back to top but stops 100 points from the top (so I can show an activity indicator to the user) and *then* after 2/3 seconds scrolls completely to the top.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right, the animations are running concurrently because scrollviews have the deceleration feature.

instead of using the DidEndDraging callback function try this one:

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

This will only be called once the user triggered animation is complete.

Comment: Thanks, that does get called when the previous animated has completed, but I don't want it to scroll back to the top at all. Can I interrupt the current animation or change the current animation somehow?

Comment: jordelver, Sorry this is not what you were looking for. You should consider clarifying the functionality you are trying to achieve. I read it a few times and it is unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post with more info. Please let me know if it's still not clear :)